# Call a jquery function from an other jquery function

Tags: jquery

I'm not very good in jquery. I will call a jquery function from another jquery function, but it won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      
    $(".publish").click(function(){
        publish=true;
        $.fn.saveData();
    });
        

    $.fn.saveData = function() {
      \\ save something in database
    }
  }
</script>
```

The publish function will be called by a button, that works well. From this function I will call the saveData function, and that fails. Something is wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: Define “it won’t work”. And why extend jQuery for non-jQuery functionality?

Comment: The function $.fn.saveData won't called

Answer (score 0):

Since you try to define `saveData` in the same scope, and since it doesn't look like the current jQuery collection matters, there's no need for a custom jQuery method - just call a standard function:

```
const saveData = () => {
  // save something in database
}
$(".publish").click(function() {
  publish = true;
  saveData();
});
```

Live demo:

```js
let publish = false;
const saveData = () => {
  // save something in database
  console.log('saving');
}
$(".publish").click(function() {
  publish = true;
  saveData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="publish">click</button>
```

Comment: I try this but it will not work, saveData will not be called

Comment: Works just fine here, see snippet

Comment: @NicovanWijk Why not?

Comment: Sorry, it works!!! 

But what is this: const saveData = () =>          Is this a function?

Comment: @NicovanWijk That is a function.

Comment: But it looks like an constante

Comment: @NicovanWijk Yes, it's preferable to declare variables with `const` (IMO), because that makes it clear that they won't be reassigned. (Functions are variables too.)

Comment: Butt normaly in javascript you declare a function as Function dataSave() {}

Comment: @NicovanWijk I (and many others) prefer using `const` because it makes it clear that the variable cannot be reassigned (and because arrow functions can be more concise in some situations, and because function declarations are hoisted, which can be counter-intuitive). You can use the `function` keyword instead, if you want, both work

Comment: @NicovanWijk "*normaly*" - not really.  "Normally" (ie frequently) people namespace their functions, so it would be something like `var nico = {}; nico.saveDate = function() { ... }; nico.saveDate();` But that's overkill for an SO sample/demonstration, just that there are numerous different ways to generate a named function

Comment: Bit of a long read, but worth knowing the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable (for fyi, not meant to answer the question)

Comment: @NicovanWijk When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)